# how to show that a function is an identity to broken rational functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-functions

Let be $ g \in \mathbb{Z} [X] $

$ g(X)= X^7 -7X^5+14 X^3-7X $

I don't know how to show that $$ g(X+ \frac{1}{X} )= X^7+ \frac{1}{X^7} $$

is an identity to broken rational functions..
Do you maybe have any Ideas?

Thank you for any help !

Comment: What do you mean by "broken rational functions"? I cannot find a definition for it. (Rational functions, yes, but what does "broken" mean here?)

Comment: by a broken rational function I mean a function in where in the dominator and nominator is a rational function

Comment: That is just called a "rational function". The ratio of two rational functions is also a rational function.

Comment: You solve this by writing out $g(x + 1/x)$ (just like that deleted answer did). Then, you recall those mysterious things called the "Binomial theorem" and "Pascal's triangle", and use them to expand each of the powers. Cancel like terms, and voila!

Comment: yes, i know that by writing out $ g( x+1/x) $ it comes out that $ x^7+ 1/x^7 $ I did not know that is enough to show.. i guess I was confused by term " identity between 2 rational function " thank you very much for your help !